# Taking time in UT to MET

Tags: python, python-datetime

I have a times in UT in the form Day/Month/Year; Hours:Minutes:Seconds.

I need to convert this to MET - or to J2000 - in terms of seconds. Is there a built in python method which will do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Middle European Time is 1 hour ahead of Coordinated Universal Time

2:46 AM Sunday, Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) is 3:46 AM Sunday, Middle European Time (MET)

So you just add an hour.

```
import time

UTC_datetime = "2016-05-05 20:28:54"

UTC_tA = time.strptime(UTC_datetime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
UTC_timestamp = time.mktime(UTC_tA)

MET_timestamp = UTC_timestamp + 3600
time_local = time.localtime(MET_timestamp)

MET_datetime = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time_local)

print MET_datetime
```